# В чем отличие notify, notifyall?

Tags: java

Я знаю, что `notify()` - пробуждает любой один поток, а `notifyAll()` - пробуждает все и даёт доступ одному. Но в чём отличие? в одних случаях работает `notify()`, а в некоторых нет, но с `notifyAll()` отлично. Как понять их?

Comment: ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/q/37026/2881286

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> There are two notification methods in the condition queue API —
>   `notify` and `notifyAll`. To call either, you must hold the lock
>   associated with the condition queue object. Calling `notify` causes
>   the JVM to select one thread waiting on that condition queue to wake
>   up; calling `notifyAll` wakes up all the threads waiting on that
>   condition queue. Because you must hold the lock on the condition queue
>   object when calling `notify` or `notifyAll`, and waiting threads
>   cannot return from wait without reacquiring the lock, the notifying
>   thread should release the lock quickly to ensure that the waiting
>   threads are unblocked as soon as possible.
>   Because multiple threads
>   could be waiting on the same condition queue for different condition
>   predicates, using `notify` instead of `notifyAll` can be dangerous,
>   primarily because single notification is prone to a problem akin to
>   missed signals.

© Brian Goetz "Java Concurrency in Practice"

Использование `notify` потенциально более бережливо к ресурсам - не приходиться выводить потоки из спячки, не приходиться парковать их обратно, потокам не приходиться драться за блокировку и процессор в момент пробуждения. Но в некоторых ситуациях пробуждение только одного потока может приводить к потере сигнала и зависанию программы.

Comment: Вот мне интересно в каких именно ситуация может произойти потеря сигнала?

Comment: В приведённой цитате Гетца как раз описан пример, который также упомянут в ответе @AntonSorokin - потоки могут ожидать наступления разных условий, если сигнал получит не тот поток, он его просто проигнорирует.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev @ AntonSorokin - в комментариях это не работает, если я не писал ничего выше, т.к. уведомления мне не пришло.

Answer (score 2):

Если коротко и без занудства - `notify` будит один какой то рандомный поток, `notifyAll`  - (внезапно ) все потоки.

**Зачем нужен первый если есть второй?** Это экономит ресурсы т.к. будить один поток очевидно быстрее, чем будить все.

**Тогда зачем нужен второй если есть первый?** Это в теории позволяет предотвратить ситуацию, когда процессорное время получает один и тот же поток.

**Что же тогда использовать?** Сильно зависит от ситуации, если вам не важно что какие то потоки будут бездельничать и постоянно спать, то используйте `notify` иначе же `notifyAll`

Answer (score 1):

`notify()` - нотифает только 1 поток, `notifyAll()` - нотифает все потоки.
Может вы пробуждаете не тот поток, который вам нужен, а `notifyAll()` пробуждает сразу все потоки.

Из [вопроса на enSO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37026/java-notify-vs-notifyall-all-over-again):

> Примером может служить набор потоков, ожидающих завершения
>   определенной задачи; как только задача будет завершена, все ожидающие
>   потоки могут продолжать свою деятельность. В таком случае вы будете
>   использовать `notifyAll()` для одновременного пробуждения всех
>   ожидающих потоков.
>
> Другой случай, например взаимоисключающая блокировка, только один из
>   ожидающих потоков может сделать что-то полезное после уведомления (в
>   этом случае получить блокировку). В таком случае вы предпочитаете
>   использовать `notify()`.

Полезные различия:

> Используйте `notify()`, если все ваши ожидающие потоки взаимозаменяемы
>   (порядок, который они просыпают, не имеет значения), или если у вас
>   только один ожидающий поток. Общим примером является пул потоков,
>   используемый для выполнения заданий из очереди - при добавлении
>   задания один из потоков уведомляется о пробуждении, выполняет
>   следующее задание и возвращается в режим сна.
>
> Используйте `notifyAll()` для других случаев, когда потоки ожидания
>   могут иметь разные цели и должны иметь возможность запускать
>   одновременно. Примером может служить операция обслуживания совместно
>   используемого ресурса, где несколько потоков ждут завершения операции
>   перед доступом к ресурсу.